# PHP string formatting (substr)

Tags: php, string, substr, strlen

I have a function that outputs a path, here are some results:

```
http://server.com/subdirectory/subdiretory/2021/12/file.txt
http://server.com/subdirectory/subdiretory/something/else/2016/16/file.txt
http://server.com/subdirectory/subdiretory/2001/22/file.txt
C:\totalmess/mess\mess/2012/06/file.txt
```

I want to cut everything from these excepting filename and two parent directories, so the ones above will look like:

```
/2021/12/file.txt
/2016/16/file.txt
/2001/22/file.txt
/20012/06/file.txt
```

So basically I have to find the third "/" from the end and display it with everything afterwards.

I don't know PHP too good, but I guess this is pretty easy to achieve with substr(), stripos() and strlen(), so:

```
$string ="http://server.com/subdirectory/subdiretory/2001/22/file.txt"
$end = strlen($string);
$slash = // How to get the right slash using stripos()?
$output = substr($string, $slash, $end);
echo $output;
```

Is this the right way of doing this, or maybe there's another in-built function that searches for -nth symbols within a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say give up on `str` functions, just `explode`, `array_slice` and `implode` it =)

```
$end='/'.implode('/',array_slice(explode('/',$string),-3));
```

Comment: You'll, of course, need to re-implode if you do this to get a string back. (Also, you don't need to pass the `3` length argument; array_slice will include up to the end of the array by default.)

Comment: @John, thanks for the note about unnecessary param, i had actually caught the `implode` before your note ;)

Answer (score -1):

Explode and then implode is real easy. But if you wanted to use a string function instead, you can use [strrpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php).

```
$string ="http://server.com/subdirectory/subdiretory/2001/22/file.txt"
$slash = strrpos( $string, '/', -3 ); // -3 should be the correct offset.
$subbed = substr( $string, $slash ); //length doesn't need to be specified.
```